# Do I use CTEs or Transactions to combine queries? postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, common-table-expression

**Documentation says:**

> **[Transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/tutorial-transactions.html)**: The essential point of a transaction is that it bundles multiple steps into a single, all-or-nothing operation. The intermediate states between the steps are not visible to other concurrent transactions, and if some failure occurs that prevents the transaction from completing, then none of the steps affect the database at all.
>
> **[Data-modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)**: This allows you to perform several different operations in the same query... The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable

**My needs:**

- All-or-nothing operation;
- Not nested queries;
- RETURNING;
- Understanding the difference & where to use each one.

**Example:** look at design bellow. What should I use here, when I CRUD data? How my request should look like?

[image: DB design]

Comment: Is there something I am missing or not understanding well?

Comment: `CTE`, since they are single query, is executed as a single transaction, so one failure will roll back whole thing. In that case I think you just need to read about CTE, examine really well done examples included in documentation and see if they fit in any of your queries. Your explanation of what you will do with those tables in insufficient to tell what would be best, since if you are talking performance or integrity, then it is more case by case. As a side note, I would also recommend to explore `foreign keys cascading on delete/update` in addition or in place of writable CTE.

Comment: if you ask for advice on usage, please provide usage examples - without the code how can we predict your usage?..

Comment: If you're asking this question, you should be using transactions and ignoring CTEs. They're something you can adopt later, once you know the basics.

Comment: @CraigRinger I used to use transactions and now I'm trying to understand CTE as well. Your answer on question ["What happens when a CTE query is interrupted"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104574/what-happens-when-a-cte-query-is-interrupted/104578#104578) was really helpful btw.